# how to get a matching status of two string using Levenshtein distance

Tags: string, matching, levenshtein-distance

is it possible to get a matching status from two compared strings, for example:

```
string 1 : this is a dog.
string 2 : this is not a cat.
```

How do I generate the below string using Levenshtein distance, could anybody help?

```
string 1 : this is     a    dog.
string 2 : this is not a cat   .
Result   : ========++++==+++---=   <<< like this.
```

I know a post has the solution that is what I need, but I have no permission to access the source code.
Could anybody help please,any comments are appreciate.

Comment: So what's your question? Someone to copy & paste that code as answer? Someone to write that code as answer?

Comment: yes, sure! if possible, you can paste the code for me, I need the code, I would appreciate.